# How to make get, post, delete methods using composite keys in api controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, composite-key

I need to get details of one patient. Id and code are the primary keys (composite key) for a patient. In api controller I have this method.

```
     public IHttpActionResult GetPatient(long? id, long? code)
    {
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id,code);
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(patient);
    }
```

To check whether it returns the details of one patient, in the web browser I enter the route as

```
http://localhost:63099/api/Patients?id=107?code=1
```

But this returns the details of all the patients and not one particular patient with this id 107 and code 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use "&" instead of "?" in case of multiple parameters in querystring

for example:- http://localhost:63099/api/Patients?id=107&code=1